# VBA: Alert if Base or 2*Base

Tags: vba, excel

I have posted this Qn at Mr Excel, but none of the solution works.

https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/1026003-vba-alert-if-base-2-base.html?posted=1#post4924266

I am re-producing the Qn here:

Using Excel 2010.
I want Excel to alert me if a cell value is NOT equal Base or 2*Base, but when a cell is NOT Base, it could be 2*Base, or vice versa; hence Excel always tells me it is wrong.

How should I modify my below code?

```
Sub SubTotal_test()
    Dim k, i, j, minim, countleft, base, tmp_row, Last_Row, rw As Integer

    base = InputBox("State the number of items")
    Last_Row = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = Last_Row + 1 To 1 Step -1

        If (ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 3) = "L" And ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 11) <> base) Then
            If (ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 3) = "L" And ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 11) <> (2 * base)) Then
                MsgBox "There is an error with the SubTotal. Please change manually."
                Exit For
            End If
        Else
            'MsgBox "SubTotal OK"
            ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 11).Select
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Just test to see whether the cell is not equal to base or base * 2:

```
Sub SubTotal_test()
    Dim k, i, j, minim, countleft, base, tmp_row, Last_Row, rw As Integer

    base = InputBox("State the number of items")
    Last_Row = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = Last_Row + 1 To 1 Step -1
        If ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 3) = "L" And _
           ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 11) <> base And _
           ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 11) <> 2 * base Then
            MsgBox "There is an error with the SubTotal. Please change manually."
            ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 11).Select
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

---

I believe you were having troubles getting it to work because you were interpreting your requirement of "if the cell value is not equal to Base or 2*Base" as "if the cell value is not equal to base or the cell value is not equal to 2*base", but you really mean "if the cell value is not (equal to base or equal to 2*base)" which can be expressed, by applying the "not" to the interior of the brackets, as "if the cell value is (not equal to base) and (not equal to 2*base)".

---

Also note that your statement

```
Dim k, i, j, minim, countleft, base, tmp_row, Last_Row, rw As Integer
```

is equivalent to the statement

```
Dim k As Variant, i As Variant, j As Variant, minim As Variant, countleft As Variant, base As Variant, tmp_row As Variant, Last_Row As Variant, rw As Integer
```

but you probably intended to use

```
Dim k As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer, minim As Integer, countleft As Integer, base As Integer, tmp_row As Integer, Last_Row As Integer, rw As Integer
```

Comment: Hi

Thank you so much! It does work. I forgot to dim i as integer.

Thank you again!

Comment: @user72728 `i` would default to a `Variant/Integer` or `Variant/Long` anyway, so failing to declare it as an integer wouldn't cause any real problems.  (It's just not a good idea to not declare it correctly.)